# Experimental foundation of particle number conservation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, experimental-physics

How can we prove that the charge is conserved in particle experiment? Or lepton and baryon conservation.

I think it is easy to say that the charge is conserved, but might be hard to measure. I guess in experiment one could not measure a single particle, instead, it should be a beam of particles.

Comment: What kind of experiment are you thinking of? At low energies, the conservation of charge is very old physics. But if you are thinking of particle accelerator physics then indeed one needs to be able to reconstruct all particles event (Especially since you have https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_shower). Which is extremely hard indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it is easy to say that the charge is conserved, but might be hard to measure.

The cart is before the horse in this sentence.

It is **because the measurements completely agree** with charge conservation that charge conservation is imposed in the mathematical models describing particle data.

> Or lepton and baryon conservation.

At elementary particle level, baryon conservation is where the classical physics assumption (again by experience and measurement ) of  conservation  of mass derives. Bulk matter is made of baryons , conservation of baryons  assures that conservation of mass will hold for macroscopic classical physics. Conservation of baryon number is a **hypothesis** necessary for the [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) to fit the existing data and to predict successfully new observations. Lepton number conservation was again **observed experimentally** and incorporated axiomatically in the standard model, with the behavior of the various forces again axiomatially assumed in the standard model.

The cart before the horse meaning that the correct order is :the horse in front to pull the cart. In this case the observations(horse) induce the theoretical model.